# "Foot pound energy Irish appearing" pun?

Tags: puns

In translating W. H. Hodgson's *The Regeneration of Captain Bully Keller*, I came across this sentence, which I suppose must be some kind of pun or joke, but I cannot understand at all.

> He knew [...] that he had administered a knock-out blow, of a *foot-energy (if I may so express it, without appearing Irish)* of several hundred pounds.

I'm quite puzzled by this one, and although I suppose the joke will get lost in translation, I'd like to know whether it's my ignorance of physics or my ignorance of jokes on Irishmen to blame.

Comment: @fdreger please undelete your answer, it's not a duplicate of Janus's at all, but it does explain nicely what a [*foot-energy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot-pound_%28energy%29) is

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This isn’t really a joke as such, but it is a pun, centered around a not-often-seen meaning of the word *Irish*. The [OED article on *Irish*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/99473) has this in sense A.5.c (*adj.*):

> *colloq.* (somewhat *offensive*). Of a statement or action: paradoxical; illogical or apparently so.

The speaker is presumably talking about boxing and thus a **fist** blow, but he measures its force in **foot**-energy. Therefore he adds “if I may say it like that without coming off too illogical, giving foot values to hand blows”.

As Compro01 points out in the comments, the *foot-energy* reference is most likely to the  Imperial unit [*foot-pound*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot-pound_%28energy%29), which measures energy (“the energy transferred on applying a force of one pound-force (lb<sub>f</sub>) through a displacement of one foot”), corresponding to the metric *joule*.

This actually makes the pun a double-pun, as it were: the unit of measurement relates to the *foot* as a unit of length, not the physical body part—but the speaker here puns on the dual meaning of the word *foot* to create a second pun on *hand vs. foot*.

There may even be a third layer to this pun, since *Irish* can also have overtones of quick-temperedness and violence; sense B.5 (*n.*) in the OED entry reads:

> *colloq.* (orig. *U.S.*). Fieriness of temper; passion, anger, rage. Chiefly with *up*, esp. in ***to get one's Irish up***.

Considering that the reference here is to a fist blow compared to feet (and thus implicitly to kicks), it may be that *Irish* here is intended not only to mean ‘paradoxical, illogical’, but also in a second, deeper layer ‘temperamental, violent’.

Comment: Quite. Most written instances of [*sounds a bit Irish*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sounds+a+bit+irish%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) are in fact nothing to do with literally *sounding* like an Irish accent. They're figurative references to concepts that seem to be illogical.

Comment: It probably has to do with imperial units of measure.  The unit of energy is the [foot-pound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot-pound_%28energy%29), and a punch from a high level boxer would probably pack several hundred foot-pounds of energy.  Coincidentally, the unit is about the same size as a Joule.

Comment: @Compro01 Thank you! I will add that to my answer later when I have the time. I did not know of this unit at all.

Comment: Thank you for going so deep in layering the meanings, I managed to save the pun using the first one, but the last one I fear is not possible to convey in just one italian word and more words would diminish the effect.