# "Childlessness is hereditary in our family" What do you call a statement containing a contradiction such as the example?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, figures-of-speech, logic

This kind of sentence is usually absurd and may or may not be recognized as such by the person who utters it.

- She will regret it till the day she dies, if she lives that long!
- "Aren't you going to John's funeral?  After all, you were best friends."  "Why should I? I'm sure he won't come to mine."

Comment: I'd call it a ***joke***!

Comment: Oxymoron or a witticism if it's meant to be funny.

Comment: From the title I would have said 'paradox', but that doesn't really fit the examples in the body of the question.

Comment: Check your science first. It could be a recessive gene.

Comment: I think you answered your own question with *absurd*.  (If you want a noun, try *absurdity*.)

Comment: Bad example, it's possible for childlessness to be hereditary in a family--lots of family members are infertile but the rest are fecund to make up for it.

Comment: `childless` can mean either a choice or a condition.  Being `barren` means you are biologically unable to bear children.  To be childless seems like it can be a choice, as there is always the ability to adopt.

Comment: @JoeDark: Is it really oxymoronic? I think this is quite the opposite: childlessness is *always* hereditary. After all, if one has no children, then his children (all zero of them) are bound to be childless. It's not a contradiction, but rather a vacuous truth.

Comment: If the person is unaware of the wittiness of the remark, it is simply an "unintentional joke". If the remark was pointed, you could call it a "one-liner" or a "zinger". But, @choster's answer is spot on.

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You ask questions when you ALREADY *know* the answer. In reality, you find a specific linguistic term, and then  pose your question feigning ignorance. This explains why you don't always accept answers, because nobody so far has come up with the term you *know* or *sustain* is the correct one.

Comment: This is where I remember seeing Irish=joke from [“Foot pound energy Irish appearing” pun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200054/foot-pound-energy-irish-appearing-pun)

Comment: @Jim was on to something. I don't think y'all had near enough fun with this yet!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The actual term is ***Irish Bull***. (Credit to *Centaurus* based on our discussion and *choster* for the related and detailed answer). In the question, it is  mentioned that it may not be recognized as such by the person who utters it. An *irish bull* can have *oxymoronic*, *self-contradictory* or *paradoxical* elements in it but it is actually an absurd statement, so it differs from more general terms like *oxymoron* or *paradox*.

> An Irish bull is a ludicrous, incongruent or logically absurd statement, generally unrecognized as such by its author.
>
> The addition of the epithet *Irish* is a late addition.
>
> The "Irish bull" is to the sense of a statement what the dangling participle is to the syntax. A jarring or amusing absurdity is created by hastiness or lack of attention to speech or writing.
>
> Example:
>
> *"He'll regret it till his dying day, if ever he lives that long."*
>
> "Red" Will Danaher, in *The Quiet Man*
>
> <sup>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_bull</sup>

---

There is a good read about *irish bull* in the below book: 
[The God of Ordinary People: A Spirituality *By Sean Caulfield*](http://books.google.ca/books?id=9O-reD-x0p0C&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=irish%20bull%20figure%20of%20speech&source=bl&ots=EisJ1a1-io&sig=RENOPR1syYbH615wBb3IySjf664&hl=en&sa=X&ei=y2ZVVILbL4eMyAT0rYGgCA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=irish%20bull%20figure%20of%20speech&f=false)

Answer (score 50):

Such quips have always been popular; recall Mark Twain on the important [role of the historian](http://books.google.com/books/about/A_Horse_s_Tale.html?id=zaL6AwAAQBAJ) as storyteller, because

> Very few things happen at the right time, and the rest do not happen at all.

Groucho Marx [opens his first autobiography admitting that](http://books.google.com/books?id=WTW-BZ7HEjwC&pg=PT27&lpg=PT27&dq=%22I%20was%20born%20at%20a%20very%20early%20age%22&source=bl&ots=G5IY4KYBZ1&sig=o4Ayr9iPeojrYvpvDTfYh9XuXyk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=tmtSVJLmI-XasASZ1ILwDA&ved=0CCMQ6AEwATgK)

> I was born at a very early age.

and remarks in a letter that

> I don’t care to belong to any club that will have me as a member.

But they were humorists; for *unintentionally* humorous— or insightful— malapropsisms, eggcorns, tautologies, and paradoxes, consider ***[Goldwynism](http://www.spectator.co.uk/life/high-life/9202491/who-needs-mrs-malaprop-when-we-have-samuel-goldwyn/)*** and especially ***[Yogiism](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/the-wisdom-of-yogi-isms/)*** (why not *Berra-ism*?), named for filmmaker Samuel Goldwyn and baseball manager Yogi Berra respectively.

To Goldwyn are attributed such turns as

> - Anybody who goes to a psychiatrist should have his head examined.
> - I'll give you a [definite maybe](http://books.google.com/books?id=f_xMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA560&lpg=PA560&dq=I%27ll%20give%20you%20a%20definite%20maybe.%20goldwyn&source=bl&ots=sHYSYyLUbs#v=onepage&q=I'll%20give%20you%20a%20definite%20maybe.%20goldwyn&f=false)

[Yogi Berra](http://yogiberramuseum.org/) is known for saying things like *Nobody goes there anymore— it's too crowded*; *When you come to a fork in the road, take it*; and *A nickel ain't worth a dime anymore*. His statements have been so widely quoted and misquoted in American media that many people are unaware that he originated such sports clichés as

> - It ain't over 'till it's over.
> - It's déjà vu all over again.

Naturally, as with Goldwyn and many others, some sayings are attributed to him even if there is no evidence he originated them. Berra himself warns:

> I really didn't say [everything I said](http://quoteinvestigator.com/2012/12/30/yogi-didnt-say/).

Comment: There is a more specific term. If you could find it I would be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: I always liked Mae West's: "When I'm good, I'm very good, but when I'm bad, I'm better."

Comment: I dunno a more specific term - I would definitely have gone with yogiism as well.

Comment: +1 for "Nobody goes there anymore— it's too crowded" - I saw the question on hot/trending, and thought "Yogi Berraism." and you nailed it.

Comment: @JohnHenckel The original example, however, is not strictly malaproprism, which is the substitution of one word for a similar-sounding word with ridiculous effect (e.g. *I resemble that remark* or, in *eggcorn* form, *a fool and his money are some party*). It is merely a paradox, but the kind of paradoxical statement that is characteristic of a Goldwyn-ism or Berra-ism, which might also, as I note, take the form of a tautology.

Comment: @choster provides a fun answer, but it strays off-topic. The OP's examples are certainly not tautologies, oxymorons, or malapropisms.

Comment: Were you aware that the "correct" answer was *Irish bull*?

Comment: Multiple answers are the point of this site, so that later searchers, who may have a subtly different goal, may still receive the answer they need without posting a question that invokes all the same answers.

Comment: +1 over accepted answer since its full of familiar terms.

Answer (score 12):

One term possibly applied to such statements is a "paradox".

Apparently, it comes from the greek word 'paradoxon', meaning contrary to expectations (http://literarydevices.net/paradox/).

Some examples that come to mind are:

- You should read a book on how to treat your illiteracy.
- There is no worse feeling than apathy.

Comment: Somehow when I have a paradox they have different opinions, and I never know which one to believe.

Comment: An example mentioned above is "I was born at a very early age". I see nothing paradoxical about that. He's basically saying that the first moment of his life was very early in his life, which is true and redundant, but not paradoxical.

Comment: @Adnan Yes but that example wasn't the OP's, and the question title is "What do you call a statement containing a contradiction?".

Comment: This answer is correct. The OP's examples are all paradoxes. None of them are oxymorons. The "epigram" answer below, though, could also be considered correct.

Answer (score 11):

A literal oxymoron - is a figure of speech that juxtaposes elements that appear to be contradictory in some cases exposing a paradox.
Childlessness - not having children
Hereditary - features passed on through act of childbirth

Comment: Literary maybe but not literal, that would be `sharpblunt`, at least that's what `oxymoron` literally means.

Comment: None of the OP's examples were oxymorons. "hereditary childlessness" would be an oxymoron, but not the full statement about a family, which is a paradox or epigram.

Comment: This is one of these confusing answers on this site that is totally wrong but for some reason has 10 votes.

Answer (score 9):

Though I am pessimistic that this is what you are looking for (as it is quite straightforward), I think that it fits the specifications:

***[self-contradictory](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/self-contradictory)***

Comment: OP is probably looking for a noun. And a noun other than "contradiction," since he used that in his title.

Answer (score 6):

The term is epigram. It's a short, usually witty, satirical, or humorous statement often with a contradictory or paradoxical twist.

Answer (score 3):

Prefer to call it plain old sarcasm, which a lot of people don't get.  Call it what you will, but isn't it wonderful some can twist words like this?  Clever, in my opinion, and witty.  "Never take life seriously, no one gets out alive."  You just have to smile, take it for what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I would call this a contrafactual statement, because if the protagonist exists, then the statement is wrong due to evidence of his own existence, if the protagonist doesn't exist, he couldn't have said it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how the obvious were left out: perhaps it was respect for the Realm?

We really should leave the Brits out of this:

## ***[Colemanball!](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/sport/telegraphsportnews/10532492/David-Coleman-dies-Top-20-Colemanballs.html)***

> “And here’s Moses Kiptanui – the 19-year-old Kenyan who turned 20 a
>   few weeks ago.”

Perhaps a sensitive decorum?

### ***[Bullshit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bullshit)***

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> Stupid or untrue talk or writing; **nonsense**.

Not only is this a perfectly good descriptor for the OP, but it is also a politically correct 21st century [alternative](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=irish%20bull&searchmode=none) from the same stock as the *ethnically insensitive* ***Irish Bull***:

> "eloquent and insincere rhetoric," 1915, American English slang;
>
> see bull (n.1) + shit (n.), probably because it smells.
>
> But bull in the sense of "trivial or false statements" (1914), which
>   usually is
>   associated with this, might be a continuation of Middle English bull
>   "false talk, fraud" (see bull (n.3)).

Then visiting [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/bullshit?s=t) we see many **delightful** back-ups:

[***Baloney***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=baloney&searchmode=none)

> Thank you Governor Alfred E.Smith from the great state of New York for
>   making it stick!

[***Bosh***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bosh&searchmode=none)

> From Turkey by way of JJ Morier novels.

[***Bunk***](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Bunk)

> Lazy Americans can't even finish Bunkum!

[***Bunkum***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bunk&searchmode=none)

> Thank you Honorable Congressman Walker, for embarrassing your home town: Buncombe, NC!

[***Hogwash***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hogwash&searchmode=none)

> Originally reserved for inferior writing.

[***Hokum***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hokum&searchmode=none)

> The illegitimate child of Bunkum and Hocus-pocus?

[***Hooey***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=hooey&searchmode=none)

> Your guess is as good as mine :-)

[***Malarkey***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/malarkey)

> Meaningless talk; nonsense: a la [Mr. Malarkey](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=malarkey&searchmode=none)?

[***Moonshine***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/moonshine)

> Foolish talk or ideas:
>   Flowing from [bottle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=malarkey&searchmode=none) to mouth and out again?

[***Phooey***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/phooey)

> [Yutzi?](http://www.yiddishslangdictionary.com/word/348/yutz) Nonsense:

[***Poppycock***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=poppycock&searchmode=none)

> The [Double-Dutch](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/double+dutch) contribution?

It's as clear as mud, but it covers the ground :-)

Answer (score -1):

It is the eqivalent to a double-negative, one side cancelling the other out.

Comment: Not quite, although I see where  you're coming from. Could you edit your answer, and include a definition and a link? Otherwise this post will not meet EL&U's standards and risks deletion. Thanks.